# How to run a basic Spring MVC Application without any IDE?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, command-line

I have created a basic Spring MVC Hello World Application, but I want to learn how to run it using command line not from the IDE?

I have created a simple Spring MVC Hello World Application with the below directory structure :

└── spring-mvc-cmd-line

```
└── src
    └── main
        ├── resources
        └── webapp
            ├── WEB-INF
            │   └── web.xml
            └── index.jsp
```

6 directories, 3 files

with Controllers , xml and jar files in the respective directories.

with Eclipse I just need to do Run as -> Server,
and with maven I do maven package and copy the war file in the tomcat webapps directory 
But how can I achieve the same output using command prompt.

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is `maven` based. You can use `mvn install`.

Comment: no , not maven based

Comment: Try to archive it as a `war` file, then `deploy` it on Apache Tomcat. You should have preferably the latest version of Apache Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you did not provide details about your Spring MVC application. I will describe it on example of Spring Boot application. I downloaded zip from https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ then unpacked and navigated to `complete` folder. In order to run application from command line you need to compile and package it first. There are 2 options available for this project: using maven or gradle. I'll show how to do it using maven:

1. Ensure that you have Maven installed: open command line for `./complete` folder and run command `mvn --version`. It should ouptut Maven version information.
2. Run `mvn package`. It should build project (at the end it outputs 'BUILD SUCCESS')
3. If 2 step was succedded, go to folder named `target`. There should be file `gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar`
4. From command line navigate to folder named `target`: `cd target`
5. Run `java -jar gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar`
6. You can terminate application, and then re-run later it using step 5.

You can package and run application using only one command (i.e. steps 2-5 are not necessary), if you run it from `./complete` folder: `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: I think yes, but then you will need to do the same work as maven (well, some of the maven work can be skipped): download all necessary dependencies from repository (even for such small project there are 39 library classes, which are included in resulting jar file) with right versions so that they can work with each other, run javac with correct classpath and switches, create some files for Spring Boot to do it's magic, package application in correct way, etc. This is just time consuming. That's why people use tools such as Maven or Gradle.

Comment: You can just package application using one of them 1 time and then simply run it using only java: `java -jar gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar`. After packaging it you don't need to use Maven or Gradle.

Comment: I completed step 4, instead of a jar file, there is a war file, is that okay?, what shall I do next?

Comment: Then you have 2 options: 1) if app contains embedded servlet container, then try to run `java -jar yourWarFile.war` from console 2) if not then run it on servlet container which it's depend on. If it's Tomcat then put it in it's `webapps` directory an run tomcat.